# Azure video indexer: Identify duplicate videos

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-video-indexer

I am trying to build a project around Azure Video Indexer. To save costs I would like to make sure there's no similar/ duplicate video already uploaded to video indexer. Is there a way to achieve/ check this before we upload video to indexer?

I tried uploading exactly similar video through video indexer portal, but they both got processed and indexed with different Id.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Video Indexer don't have de-duplication support.
In case you have identical files, you can use MD5 to detect they are already indexed.